# Import realm from old version to new Keycloak version

Tags: keycloak

We need to export & import configuration from an old version 3.4 to new Keycloak version 5. But it shows error on import:

> {"errorMessage":"App doesn't exist in role definitions: realm-management"}

Is there any option to import realm to new version?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

For me, I needed to create the realm using the Add Realm button and use the export file as the import file on the realm creation screen. I think the realm just needs to be created alongside the import.

Comment: In my case that caused: Error! An unexpected server error has occurred

Answer (score 0):

[Mouse in Left menu -> arrow -> the button "Add realm" will appear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8sqfY.png)